# Disable Chrome running in background for Enterprise

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to disable chrome running in the background after closing for enterprise users with the master_preferences file.  Cannot find the right syntax to deploy this.

Does anyone have a more comprehensive list of settings available within chrome preferences?

Answer (score 0):

In search bar type Task Manager click on it. And under processes find Google Chrome, right click that and click End Task. And make sure that in the startup section, status is disabled for chrome or if it's not right click on that and disable it, It gonna disable the chrome to startup when you boot your PC.

Answer (score -1):

hold down esc and refresh and power off and then do ctrl d and at last press enter and that should work

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a combination of keys that would have any impact on Chrome whatsoever, nor does it impact Chrome in an enterprise environment.